# Limit memory usage NXT client

Tags: runescape

I noticed that the RuneScape NXT client uses about 1.6 GB of memory when I am in the Living Rock Caverns on the LRC world, even when I have all graphics options turned down. While I have 4 GB memory on this system, this much memory for that application makes my system unstable. The old java client didn't seem to have this problem.

Is there a settings file that allows me to limit the amount of memory, or an other way that allows me to hint the application to only use about 1GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't decrease the memory usage via a configuration setting. Unlike the old Java client, which could only use memory up to a limit that could be set through JVM startup options, the C++-based NXT client can use as much memory as it needs, up to the total available system memory.

This is a good thing. Unused memory is wasted memory. If you're having issues due to your computer running out of memory, try closing other memory-intensive programs (Chrome is a common culprit), or upgrading your RAM (4 GB is a bit on the low side nowadays).

Comment: It's... interesting to read that an application using so much memory that it literally freezes the system, sometimes requiring a power cycle to get out of it, is "a good thing". Nevertheless, it does not seem to answer the question I had...

Comment: @Sumurai8 I did answer the question - you can't decrease the memory usage via a configuration setting. If your computer is freezing up, it's more likely that something else is going on that's causing it.